# Enums as value objects and modularisation

Tags: grails, plugins, enums

I would like to split a Grails app in smaller plugins. Some domain classes have attributes which are of type Enum. Some values from these Enums would logically be part of the plugins, so I'm looking for a way for each plugin to register its own values into the 'core' Enums.

Obviously this cannot be done with Enums as they cannot be modified at runtime.

One option I see is replacing every Enum with a class with static attributes and add a static method to register new values from plugins. This has the following consequences:

- GORM will not know what to store for the fake Enum values so it will throw an Exception
- Therefore, I would have to change the type of these attributes to String, this way it will still work with the present values in storage, but I lose the advantage of seeing where that attribute can take its values.

Is there a better way to do this? Am I taking an approach which is not the "Grails way"?

In the end I am looking for a way to do an extension point in the core app for the plugins, like I would do with a ServiceProvider in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you are over complicating this problem,  I would define the enums in different files depending on their type as probably they are now, then use them across your applications. I personally prefer to group the enums by their type not by their application, but it depends on your design.

Regarding the extension point, if you define them in core plugin, by the nature of Grails plugin you will have extendability. Meaning your applications can override or extend those values.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your input! The problem is that currently I need to split a big Enum into smaller ones for each plugin and I also need to have a centralised version of all the values of this Enum (so including the values defined in all the plugins) to display them. I'm pretty convinced that this cannot be done with Enums and I agree that maybe a different way of approaching this is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem in the development process. There is one solution I've found.

Transfer your enums to domains and init values with your plugins. Make static methods to get values, so domains will look like enums. For example:

```
     class Person { 
       String name

       static mapping = {
            cache usage: 'read-only'
            table 'Person '
            id column: 'Person ID', generator: 'identity'
            name column: 'Name'
       }

       static Person getJOHN() {
            getByName('John')
       }

       static Person getByName(String name) {
            Person.findByName(name)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm not a very big fan of this solution, because it would transfer the Enums in the database which I don't want.

Comment: There is another hack. In groovy enums is not final by default. So you can change values in runtime, but it's very bad =)

Comment: Uuhh, I wouldn't go that way either :))